# How to call C extern function and get return struct?

Tags: c, windows, call, nasm, extern

I have an extern function and a `struct` defined in `token.c`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct token {
    int start;
    int length;
} t;

extern t get_token(int, int);

t get_token(int s, int l) {
    printf("[C] new token: start [%d]  length [%d]\n\n", s, l);

    t m_T = {};
    m_T.start = s;
    m_T.length = l;

    return m_T;
}
```

... so that I can call `_get_token` from my assembly and get a new token. In make_token.asm I have the following:

```
SECTION .data       ; initialized data
    mtkn:       db  "call: token(%d, %d)", 10, 0
    mlen        db  "length: %d", 10, 0
    mstt:       db  "start: %d", 10, 0

    mend:       db  10, "*** END ***", 10, 0

SECTION .text       ; code
    extern _get_token

    extern _printf

    global _main

    _main:
        ;   stash base stack pointer
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,        esp

        mov     eax,        5
        mov     ebx,        10
        push    ebx                     ; length
        push    eax                     ; start
        call    _get_token              ; get a token
        mov     [tkn],      eax

        add     esp,        8

        ;   test token properties
        push    DWORD [tkn]
        push    mstt
        call    _printf

        push    DWORD [tkn + 4]
        push    mlen
        call    _printf

        add     esp,        16

        .end:
        push    DWORD   mend
        call    _printf
        ;   restore base stack pointer
        mov     esp,        ebp
        pop     ebp

SECTION .bss        ; uninitialized data
    tkn:        resd        1
```

The output is:

> [C] new token: start [5]  length [10]
>
> start: 5
>   length: 0

What am I missing to get both start and length? The output verifies that the extern function in C is getting called and the values are pushed into the function.

Comment: If I read [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) correctly than second half of your answer should be in EDX - "POD return values 33-64 bits in size are returned via the EAX:EDX registers."

Comment: 1) do not typedef struct definitions.  2) since that struct is declared in a different file the definition should be in a header file, that both source files #include.  3) referencing an external function is not done via extern. rather in a common header file, that is included in both the source file where the function is declared and in the local file via #include.  the header file would have the prototype, the linker handles the rest. 4) the search order for #include files depends on weither '< ...>' or '"..."' is used.  system headers should always use the '<' and '>'

Comment: this line: ' return m_T;' will not work correctly, because when the function exits, anything on the stack is 'lost'  so returning an item that is on the stack is undefined behaviour.   However, since the actual full struct is being returned, rather than a pointer, the compiler will invoke memcpy() to copy the struct to a 'hidden' memory area (that cannot be used for anything else) then invoke memcpy() again to copy from the hidden memory area to the callers' variable.   Much better to pass a third parameter that is a pointer to the callers' instance of the struct, and use that pointer

Comment: please use meaningful variable/parameter names.  's' and 'l'  and 't' have little or no indication of the content nor their usage

Comment: assuming the posted assembly code is a faithful reproduction, then the compiler only handled the first field of the struct, I.E. it failed to copy/return the second field

Comment: If you want to know how something is done on your system and don't know where to check it you can also write simple C program and check generated assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided instead of a single token at a time, that I should allocate a buffer and fill it: determine how many tokens are required, `malloc` the buffer, call `get_tokens` and pass in the pointer to the buffer and number of tokens.

The `get_tokens` method fills the buffer and returns a count of tokens created.

The assembly then iterates the token buffer and displays the values - `start` and `length` - for each token.

**token.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct token {
    int start;
    int length;
} t;

extern int get_tokens(t*, int);
extern int token_size();

/*
    p_t: pointer to allocated buffer
    num: number of tokens with which to fill buffer
*/
int get_tokens(t* p_t, int num) {
    printf("[C] create %d tokens: %d bytes\n", num, token_size() * num);
    int idx = 0;

    while (idx < num) {
        //  values are arbitrary for testing purposes
        t tkn = {idx, idx * 10};
        p_t[idx] = tkn;
        printf("[C] [%d] start: %d; len: %d\n", idx, tkn.start, tkn.length);

        ++idx;
    }

    return idx;
}

int token_size() {
    return sizeof(t);
}
```

**make_tokens.asm**:

```
SECTION .data       ; initialized data
    endl:       db  10, 0
    mszt:       db  "token size: %d bytes", 10, 0
    tk_info:    db  "[%d]: s[%d] l[%d]", 10, 0
    mlen        db  "length: %d", 10, 0
    mstt:       db  "start: %d", 10, 0

    mend:       db  10, "*** END ***", 10, 0

    mt1         db  "malloc space for 3 tokens: %d bytes", 10, 0
    mty         db  10, "success", 10, 0
    mtn         db  10, "fail", 10, 0

SECTION .text       ; code
    extern _get_tokens
    extern _token_size

    extern _free
    extern _malloc
    extern _printf

    global _main

    _main:
        ;   stash base stack pointer
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp,        esp

        ;   get token size
        call    _token_size
        mov     [tsz],      eax

        push    DWORD [tsz]
        push    DWORD mszt
        call    _printf
        add     esp,        8

        mov     eax,        [tsz]
        mov     edx,        3               
        mul     edx
        mov     [tbsz],     eax

        push    DWORD [tbsz]
        push    DWORD mt1
        call    _printf
        add     esp,        8

        push    DWORD [tbsz]               ; malloc 3 tokens
        call    _malloc
        mov     [tkn_buf],  eax
        add     esp,        4

        mov     ecx,        3               ; 3 tokens
        push    DWORD ecx
        push    DWORD [tkn_buf]
        call    _get_tokens
        add     esp,        8
        cmp     eax,        3
        je      .yes

        .no:
        push    DWORD mtn
        call    _printf
        add     esp,        4
        jmp     .end

        .yes:
        push    DWORD mty
        call    _printf
        add     esp,        4

        mov     ecx,        0
        mov     ebx,        [tkn_buf]
        .loopTokens:
            mov     eax,    [tsz]       ; determine next token
            mul     ecx                 ; start location => eax

            mov     edi,    ecx         ; preserve counter

            push    DWORD [ebx + eax + 4]   ; length
            push    DWORD [ebx + eax]       ; start
            push    DWORD ecx
            push    DWORD tk_info
            call    _printf
            add     esp,    16

            mov     ecx,    edi
            inc     ecx
            cmp     ecx,    3
            jl      .loopTokens

        .end:
        push    DWORD [tkn_buf]
        call    _free

        push    DWORD mend
        call    _printf
        ;   restore base stack pointer
        mov     esp,        ebp
        pop     ebp

SECTION .bss        ; uninitialized data
    tkn_buf:    resd        1
    tbsz:       resd        1
    tsz:        resd        1
```

...and the resulting output:

> token size: 8 bytes
>   malloc space for 3 tokens: 24 bytes
>   [C] create 3 tokens: 24 bytes
>   [C] [0] start: 0; len: 0
>   [C] [1] start: 1; len: 10
>   [C] [2] start: 2; len: 20
>
> success
>   [0]: s[0] l[0]
>   [1]: s[1] l[10]
>   [2]: s[2] l[20]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in your `.bss` section:

```
SECTION .bss        ; uninitialized data
    tkn:        resd        1
```

Here, you set aside a single `dword` (one integer's worth of memory) of memory for the token. However, in your C code, you define the token struct as having 2 `int`s (`start` and `length`), or 2 `dword`s worth of memory. This means that you are only able to write to part of the token struct (`start`), and the member `length` is treated as non-existent. Your problem can probably be solved by simply defining `tkn` as

```
    tkn:        resd        2
```

or

```
    tkn:        resq        1     ;; 1 QWORD == 2 DWORDs
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
As I stated in a comment.
it would be far better to pass a pointer to 
an instance of struct token
rather than the current code.
The following follows the current code.
but remember all those hidden calls to memcpy()
and the hidden ram allocation
```

otherfile.h contains

```
#ifndef OTHER_FILE_H
#define OTHER_FILE_H

struct token 
{
    int start;
    int length;
};

struct token get_token( int, int );

#endif // OTHER_FILE_H
```

in file otherfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "otherfile.h"

struct token get_token( int tokenStart, int tokenLength ) 
{
    printf("[C] new token: start [%d]  length [%d]\n\n", s, l);

    struct token m_T = {0,0};
    m_T.start = tokenStart;
    m_T.length = tokenLength;

    return m_T;
}
```

in file token.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "otherfile.h"
...
    struct token myToken = {0,0};
    myToken = get_token( tokenStart, tokenLength );
...
```

Comment: BTW, I still have to have something extern in order to invoke from assembly. The sample code I have in my question is based on very sketchy details at best and how to create an externally accessible function.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't see how this offers any solution to the question.